# User redirect when UIView with UIImageView is clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIView , and inside that view i add a UIImageView with an image inside of it , using this method :

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageAdName]];    
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data]];
imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);
[_ad1 addSubview:imgView];
```

I want, when the user touches this view, to be redirected through safari to an external website which i indicate the url. How can i do that? 
 Many Thanks!

Comment: why not use a UIButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you would only need to add a gesture recognizer to the `UIImageView` which you intend the user to tap:

```
UIImageView *imgView;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                   action:@selector(imageViewTapped:)];
[imgView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];


- (void)imageViewTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:yourURL];
}
```

If the URL to be loaded in Mobile Safari depends on which particular image view was tapped, then you have more work to do.  Possibly you could subclass `UIImageView` so that it has a property for the URL it's associated with.  (Although that doesn't really sound like a proper role for view.)